# Javascript Link to Href maker not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple link to html maker, but the thing is variables aren't working

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
var link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
var input = document.getElementById("thetext");
var flink1 = "<a href='" + link1.value + "'>" + text1.value + "</a>";

function generate() {
  input.value = flink1
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="thetext" class=""></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input id="link1" placeholder="link"></input><br/><br/>
<input id="text1" placeholder="link title"></input><br/><br/>
<button id="" onclick="generate()"></button>
```

Can anyone say what's the issue

Comment: you need to wrap your javascript in a script tag

Comment: Put all of that javascript inside the `generate()` function. Right now all those variables are being set to null on page load, and they never change; the function just copies that null value into the input.

Comment: You are building `flink1` _before_ user even entered anything, directly after page load

Comment: (The missing script tag was only because they slightly mangled the format for a stack overflow snippet, guys)

Comment: as @Justinas said.you are building  flink1 before user even entered anything
   https://jsfiddle.net/toj9fmg7/1/

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `flink1` will always contain empty strings for `href` and `innerText` because your `generate` doesn't update its value upon user input.

Move the variable definition inside `generate` call, and it'll work as intended.

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
var link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
var input = document.getElementById("thetext");

function generate() {
  var flink1 = "<a href='" + link1.value + "'>" + text1.value + "</a>";
  input.value = flink1
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="thetext" class=""></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input id="link1" placeholder="link"></input><br/><br/>
<input id="text1" placeholder="link title"></input><br/><br/>
<button id="" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your answer.

```js
function generate() {
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
var link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
var input = document.getElementById("thetext");
var flink1 = "<a href='" + link1.value + "'>" + text1.value + "</a>";
input.value = flink1;
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<textarea id="thetext" class=""></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input id="link1" placeholder="link"></input><br/><br/>
<input id="text1" placeholder="link title"></input><br/><br/>
<button id="" onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
```